# 404 not found - notification URL - adyen payemts

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.1.6

I have implemented adyen-magento2 paymets. I am facing issue related to adyen notification url:

I am using following url: SiteURL/adyen/process/json

When i test configuration. I am getting following results
HTTP test - Merchant Account:

```
Test 1: test_AUTHORISATION_1
ResponseTime_ms: 315
ResponseCode: 404
Output:
Error 404: Not Found
Test 2: test_AUTHORISATION_2
ResponseTime_ms: 315
ResponseCode: 404
Output:
Error 404: Not Found
Test 3: test_AUTHORISATION_3
ResponseTime_ms: 315
ResponseCode: 404
Output:
Error 404: Not Found
Test 4: test_AUTHORISATION_4
ResponseTime_ms: 315
ResponseCode: 404
Output:
Error 404: Not Found
```

It is only giving 404, when i test configuration through adyen. It is giving me unauthorized 401 return code which is correct.

Can any body know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

For the 404, if you turned off URL rewrite in Magento, then you will need to preprend `index.php`

```
index.php/adyen/process/json
```

Otherwise, A HTTP status code of 401 implies that the `Notification Username` and `Notification Password` that you set on Magento doesn't match what you put on Adyen.

Comment: url rewrite is enable. It is returning 401 when i tried from postman but when i test configuration. It return 404 on adyen server configuration.

Comment: Sounds like it could be discrepancy between LAN and WAN. Adyen's notifications come from WAN so ensure that your DNS and domain setup is correct and perform sanity checks (spelling and such). Reach out to support@adyen.com if you want to provide them more information to dig deeper.

Comment: @luck_b. May be that is the case. I already reach out to support. But there suggestion is not helpful yet. I forget to mention that i am using default AWS domain. If i create a module in magento 2 and return the accepted response and set that url in notification url of adyen. It accepted and worked. But when i used the same class. It doesn't work.